# subscribe to events in tfs extension using VSS SDK

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, vssdk

Im developing a TFS Extension using VSS SDK and Angular.
I would like to subscribe to events that occurred in the TFS so it will trigger a function in my extension.

for example, I would like to listen to update of specific work item and perform an action in my extension when that event is happened.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You can consider using C# client api with TFS `WorkItemChanged event`. Similar tickets [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531239/listening-to-tfs-work-item-state-change-using-c-sharp-window-service),[#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002496/tfs-2013-event-handling-on-work-item-change) and [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451282/is-isubscriber-still-supported-in-tfs2018).

Comment: I would like to do it in the extension itself using the vss sdk, is it possible?

Comment: I've checked the document of Azure-devops extension package, but  I didn't find such event you can subscribe to in VSS package.